# load-string doesn't work in for loop

Tags: for-loop, clojure

In REPL, this code worked just fine and gives the answer 36

```
(do
  (load-string (str "(def yyy" 2 " 18)"))
  (* 2 yyy2))
```

While it wouldn't work when I introduced a for loop into it

```
(do
 (for [x [1 2 3]]
  (load-string (str "(def yyyy" x " 18)")))
 (* 2 yyyy2))
```

The error said unable to resolve symbol yyyy2, which should have been defined within load-string. Can some expert explain the reason for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) produces a lazy sequence thus `load-string` expression won't be evaluated until you force its evaluation. You can force it by wrapping `for` in [`dorun`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun) or [`doall`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall).

For cases where you only need the side effects you should use [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) or when you just need to iterate over a range of numbers [`dotimes`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dotimes) might also be handy.

Comment: Instead of wrapping `for` in `dorun` or `doall`, you should just replace `for` with [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq).

Comment: @SamEstep You're right - I have edited my answer. Thanks!